# Prove that $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\sin x$ for $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to prove that
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\sin x
$$
for $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}$ using Taylor exapnsion?

**My attempt**: By Taylor Theorem we can write $f(x)=x\sin x$ around $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ as
$$
x\sin x=\frac{\pi}{2}+(x-\frac{\pi}{2})+R(x)
$$
where $R(x)$ is the remainder. But in this case $R(x)<0$ in the interval $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}$, which gives us noting interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not a full answer.

Maybe, it's easier to calculate the derivative in general. By induction, one can prove
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x\cdot \sin(x)\right)=\begin{cases}
x\sin(x)-n\cos(x),&n\equiv0\pmod 4\\
x\cos(x)+n\sin(x),&n\equiv1\pmod 4\\
-x\sin(x)+n\cos(x),&n\equiv2\pmod 4\\
-x\cos(x)-n\sin(x),&n\equiv3\pmod 4.
\end{cases}
$$

Now, we have

$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x\cdot \sin(x)\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2},&n\equiv0\pmod 4\\
n,&n\equiv1\pmod 4\\
-\frac{\pi}{2},&n\equiv2\pmod 4\\
-n,&n\equiv3\pmod 4.
\end{cases}
$$

Further observe $\sin(\xi)>0$ and $\cos(\xi)\leq 0$ for $\xi\in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3}{4}\pi]$,

$$
x\sin(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{1!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2!\cdot 2}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2-\frac{3}{3!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4!}(\xi(x)\sin(\xi(x))-4\cos(\xi(x)))\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^4}_{R(x):=}\quad\text{and}\quad R(x)\geq 0
$$

Hence,
$$x\sin(x)\geq \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{1!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2!\cdot 2}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2-\frac{3}{3!}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3.$$

It's not relevant, but it holds $\left|\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x\cdot \sin(x)\right)\right|\leq n+1$.